# Intern in USA, can I go to Chile?

Tags: visas, usa, chile, j1-visas, greek-citizens

I want to travel to Santiago, Chile before late September. My J-1 Visa expires at 31 Dec. I am from Greece.

Can I just jump into a plane and go, or...?

Comment: You should check with your visa sponsor before you leave the US, to make sure you'll be allowed to re-enter. When I was on a J-1, I was told I'd need to get a "travel authorisation" signature from my sponsor on my DS-2019, otherwise I might not be allowed back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering you are a Greece passport holder you can simply hop on a plane and go to Chile for a stay of up to 90 days. Greece nationals do not need a visa if they intend to visit Chile for less than 90 days.

Kindly make sure your passport is at least 90 days till expiry, prefer to be 6 months.

resourceful links:

https://chile.visahq.com/requirements/Greece/resident-United_States/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Greek_citizens

https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=GR&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CL&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C

If you want to clear any confusions you can call the embassy @202-785-1746